# Stack Exchange site to ask for deprecated and removed PHP functions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I find the deprecated and removed PHP function from 5.0.0 and 7.0.0 as I am upgrading a site to PHP version 8.2.0? Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: If all you're going to be asking for is a list, probably none. [Real questions have answers, not *items*, ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) (emphasis mine). Also see the [/help/dont-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page on each site, they mention not asking questions where every answer is equally valid and questions where there is no actual problem to be solved. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I am updating my system which relies on php 7 and as I understand this is not a code writing service but a Q&A site I am asking for a site where I can get a list of derprecated and removed php 5,7 function to update it to v8 so please kindly forgive me for my not understanding this, please give me insights. Thanks

Comment: @Tinkeringbell since I have not followed the guidelines whilst asking this question should I delete it?

Comment: You can not delete answered questions, so you don't even need to ask me, the answer is no.

Comment: What you need is a migration guide [like this one](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php).

Comment: @Braiam YES!, Phew thanks bro. This is exactly what I was looking for, it has all the changed function added functions and features plus more than I even asked for thanks so much. Your comment made my day. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Please don't remove correct tags, if you don't know or understand what is some specific tag, ask before removing it. This question is purely site recommendation, so please leave the tag in place.

Comment: K thanks @ShadowWizardChasingStars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> a list of deprecated functions of programming languages?

That's *really* broad. Even for a single language.

I'd point you at what sorts of [questions not to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Lists don't generally solve 'real problems' - and are not a great fit for the Q&A format. Its too broad and unfocused for a good question and is likely to be closed.

So in short - no, there's no site that's a good fit for this question